# Unable to send IR command

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, ir

I am trying to switch the TV on using Arduino. Following is my set of code

```
#include <IRremote.h>

IRrecv receiver(2);
IRsend sender;
decode_results results;

long repeatitions;
long count;
unsigned int durations[100];
void (*reset)(void) = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  receiver.enableIRIn();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    repeatitions = Serial.parseInt();
    count = Serial.parseInt();
    for (int i =0; i < repeatitions; i++) {
      durations[i] = Serial.parseInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatitions; i++) {
      Serial.println("sending code");
      sender.sendRaw(durations, count, 40);
      delay(50);
    }
    reset();
  }
  if (receiver.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    Serial.print(results.rawlen - 1);
    for (int i =1; i <results.rawlen;i++) {
      unsigned int number = results.rawbuf[i] * USECPERTICK;
      Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(number);
    }
    Serial.println("");
    receiver.resume();
  }
}
```

The code receiving part works fine. And it returned me following code:

```
A90
25,2400,600,1200,600,600,550,1200,600,600,600,1200,600,600,600,550,600,1200,600,600,600,600,550,650,600,600
```

But when I try to use the same code to switch the TV on after adding durations to the above returned code it doesn't work. I am entering following into the serial monitor

```
3,25,2400,600,1200,600,600,550,1200,600,600,600,1200,600,600,600,550,600,1200,600,600,600,600,550,650,600,600
```

I have attached a screenshot to show how I have installed the IR Transmitter LED.
[image]

I have two IR Transmitters. I have tried installing both in same manner 1 by 1. But unfortunately no success.

I am using IRRemote library by Shirriff https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

Comment: Where's your resistor?

Comment: This seems unlikely to work for many reasons.  Presumably you are following some guide but have gone somewhat astray, you need to include a link to that and the exact IR library you are using in the question.  In addition to the LED electrical issues (generally a transistor and series resistor are needed), pin 12 doesn't seem to be a usual output for IR sending on an ATmega328p - rather, it is usually pin 3 or 9.

Comment: I thought when using IR LED bulb the resistor wasn't required so I didn't include that in the circuit. Can you kindly share some circuit diagram that I should use in order to make the circuit work? Thanks

Comment: This would be in the instructions for whatever library you are using - I'd point out again that you have failed to identify which one you are using.

Comment: I have already mentioned the name of the library in the original question as you suggested. I am using IRRemote library by Shirriff https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote

Comment: is the LED actually lighting up? use your smartphone camera to see IR light